# Why Google Translate hangs my Zebra Datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, google-translate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkin').Zebra_DatePicker({
            direction: true,
            show_icon:false,
            format: 'M d, Y',
            show_select_today:false,
         pair: $('#checkout')
        });

        $('#checkout').Zebra_DatePicker({
                direction: 1,
                show_icon:false,
                format: 'M d, Y'
            });
         });         
    </script>


    <script>
    $(function() {
    $("#checkin").Zebra_datepicker();
    $('.Zebra_Datepicker dp_visible').addClass('notranslate');
    });
</script>
```

I am using Zebra Datepicker on my website but When I use Google Translate API with in my website Google Translate hangs my Datepicker and keep on translating  Need help....
I am trying to use the above function to add no translate class to ui-datepicker but no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.Zebra_DatePicker').addClass('notranslate');
});
```

Try this!